Boundedness of the modulus of continuity
According to Wikipedia, the modulus of continuity is "used to measure quantitatively the uniform continuity of functions", and is defined as follows:
For a function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ admits $\omega$ as a modulus of continuity if
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \omega(|x-y|)
$$
for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$, such that $\omega (t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.
A function is uniformly continuous if and only if it admits a modulus of continuity
In Taylor's PDEs I in page 133 the following is stated

Let $\omega: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$be a modulus of continuity, i.e., $\omega(0)=0, \omega$ is continuous, and increasing. We may as well assume $\omega$ is bounded and $C^{\infty}$ on $(0, \infty)$.

My question is, on what basis we can assume $\omega$ is bounded and $C^{\infty}$ on $(0, \infty)$?
Can we expect every uniformly continuous function to have a bounded $\omega$?
Alternatively, $\omega$ is sometimes defined by
$$
\omega_f(\delta) = \sup_{|x-y| \leq \delta} |f(x) - f(y)|.
$$
From this definition, it is obvious that if $f$ is bounded then $\omega_f$ is also bounded.
Is this also true?

In my book version (in fact the one you linked), it is explained.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Can you tell me where, please? Because after the passage I gave from the book, there is a proposition. Unless I am missing something here.

Sorry, I confused something. I meant the proposition before. You approximate $F$ by a mollified version $F_j = \varphi_jF$ (do you know this concept), from which you deduce that the modulus of continuity of $F_j$ is $\varphi_j\omega$, which is smooth. I think the boundedness comes from the fact that you only need the modulus of continuity in a bounded ball, but I could be wrong about that.

The answer to your last question is positive.
Since $f$ is bounded then there exists $M>0$ such that for all $x \in \text{Dom}(f)$ we have $|f(x)| \leq M$.
By your last definition we have
$$0<\omega_f(\delta) = \sup_{|x-y| \leq \delta} |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \sup_{|x-y| \leq \delta} |f(x)| + |f(y)| \leq 2M.$$
This shows that $\omega_f$ is bounded.
